# NFFT Undefined Reference To NNFFT Functions

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, undefined-reference

So I am trying to install the NFFT3 package from https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/nfft/.

It seemed to install okay, using the standard configure, make, make install commands. However I get the error:

```
simple_test.o: In function 'simple_test_nnfft_1d':
simple_test.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to 'nnfft_init'
simple_test.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to 'nnfft_precompute_one_psi'
simple_test.c:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to 'nnfft_trafo_direct'
simple_test.c:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to 'nnfft_trafo'
simple_test.c:(.text+0x19d): undefined reference to 'nnfft_finalize'`
```

The thing is, the file `simple_test.c` for the regular NFFT works just fine. Does anybody know how to fix this? I know this is some kind of linking problem, but the software is so large that I am at a loss at how to fix it.

Thanks

Edit: So in the directory kernel/nnfft there is nnfft.c with all the required functions, but still no header file. Does anyone know where the header with these declarations is actually located? I included the nnfft.c file at the top of the test code and got it to compile, but that doesn't help with the problem of linking originally.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Sorry I am not some kind of super programmer or super software architect. Maybe I just need to use it for more mundane purposes, not understand the ins and outs of its construction. Some advice or help would be nice, you know...jeez...

Answer (score 0):

First run `ldconfig` to cache the library. Then run gcc with `-lnfft3`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the NNFFT module is not compiled by default.

You have to add the option `--enable-nnfft` to do that when configuring:

```
./configure --enable-nnfft
```